# Setting a TImage's Parent

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have a class

```
THexMap = Class(TScrollingWinControl)
  private
      FCanvas    :timage;    // the canvas to draw on.
```

Dureing the constructor I create  TImage Like so.

```
Constructor THexMap.Create(AOwner: Tcomponent);
    begin
      inherited Create(AOwner);

      FCanvas := timage.Create(self);
      FCanvas.Visible := true;

      { Set intial property values for component }

      MakeSolidMap;

    end;
```

If i try to set the parent here like so

```
FCanvas.parent := THexMap;
```

I get `Incompatible types: TWinControl and Class of ThexMap`

How do i make it so this image shows up inside the THexMap?

SOME MORE INFO THAT MIGHT HELP...
If i set the create like so
`FCanvas := TImage.Create(AOwner);`
The `TImage` is on the forum, but no image shows up. If i click on the component in the Object Inspector and then click on the property Picture, the correct image will show in the picture Editor.

THE REDRAW..

```
procedure THexMap.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
const
  DISCARD_CURRENT_ORIGIN = nil;
var
  R : TRect;
  PS : PAINTSTRUCT;
begin
  if Message.Msg = WM_PAINT then
  begin
    if GetUpdateRect( Handle, nil, false ) then
    begin
      BeginPaint( Handle, PS );
      try
        R := PS.rcPaint;
        bitblt(fCanvas.Canvas.Handle, R.Left, R.Top, R.Width, R.Height, TempMap.Canvas.Handle, R.Left+FOffset.X, R.Top+FOffset.Y, SRCCOPY);
      finally
        EndPaint( Handle, PS );
      end;
    end
    else
      inherited;
  end
  else
    inherited;



end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parent is **an instance** of TWinConrol, not class type
(e.g. this boy's parent is John Doe, not mankind)
So you have to write:

```
FCanvas := timage.Create(self);
FCanvas.Parent := Self;
```

Visible = true is not needed here

Comment: Great, I cant belive i did not try this... IT does solve the parent issue i had, though the image is still not showing up... Unless i am dragging the component around , then the image shows up till i stop dragging the component around but sounds like another question..... But at least the TIMage is now inside the component..

Comment: @GlenMorse Setting the control parent should not be try/error but reading documentation how/to. BTW At what time did you set the size of that image control?

Comment: WinControl initiates child controls redrawing automatically under repaint (TWinControl.PaintHandler). Is your TScrollingWinControl redrawed after 'dragging'? You can try InvalidateRect to ensure.

Comment: @SirRufo i set the FCanvas width / height just after the `Fcanvas.parent := self;`   inside the `makeSolidMap` it does do an `invalidateRect(Self.Handle, r, False);` with a refresh at the end, Also to redraw, i also use a  `THexMap.WndPRoc()`  i added that uptop

Comment: Thanks for help on question, Now I am just getting `Control '' has no parent window`  So i must have something else going on.. Thanks

Comment: This is strange issue for TImage. It is possible for Tcombobox and other Windows controls, and assigning parent in CreateWnd helps.